# Adding guidelines to a TextBox/RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, richtextbox

Is there any way to show gridlines on a multiline textbox or a richtextbox?
Perhaps by overriding the OnPaint event?

I am using the textbox to insert address information, for each line it would be something like:

> Street
>   City
>   Country
>   etc.

I am using WinForms with C#.

Comment: Why do you need gridlines in a textbox? A textbox is not a grid.

Comment: Just to make it look a bit nicer.

Comment: Not likely.  Given the nature of those controls, I doubt any level of override is going to work.  They're stubborn.  You'd probably have to invent a new control ground-up.

Comment: You can make a work around for this scenario like

Take 3 text boxes and each text box Y location should immediately begin with Y axis of previous box+2 and make all the  text boxes border style to none. and draw a rectangle using Graphics Calss and draw a line between text boxes in OnPaint

Comment: @BhanuChowdary - That could work yes but I wont be able to copy the text in one shot from all 3 textboxes - I would like to keep it one textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using one of these methods:

- Customize Paint of TextBox
- Using RTF Tricks

and here is a screenshot of these 2 ways:

[image]

I recommend using first method if you really want this feature.

**1- Customizing Paint of TextBox**

---

Customizing textbox paint in not straightforward. You can customize paint of TextBox in different ways. here is 2 way of customize painting of TextBox.

**1-1 Customizing Paint of TextBox using NativeWindow**

---

In this way should subclass a TextBox using [NativeWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow(v=vs.110).aspx) and handle WM_PAINT in window procedure. Here is a complete code listing that implements what you need.

To use code it is enough to pass your textbox to an instance of CustomPaintTextBox:

```
var t = new CustomControls.CustomPaintTextBox(this.textBox1);
```

And here is the code of CustomPaintTextBox

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
namespace CustomControls
{
    public class CustomPaintTextBox : NativeWindow
    {
        private TextBox parentTextBox;
        private const int WM_PAINT = 15;
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_PAINT: 
                    // invalidate textbox to make it refresh
                    parentTextBox.Invalidate();
                    // call default paint
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    // draw custom paint
                    this.CustomPaint();
                    break;
                default:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }
        public CustomPaintTextBox(TextBox textBox)
        {
            this.parentTextBox = textBox;
            textBox.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
            // subscribe for messages
            this.AssignHandle(textBox.Handle);
        }
        void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CustomPaint();
        }
        private void CustomPaint()
        {
            var g= this.parentTextBox.CreateGraphics();
            float y = 0;
            var lineHeight = g.MeasureString("X", this.parentTextBox.Font).Height;
            while (y < this.parentTextBox.Height)
            {
                y += lineHeight;
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0f, y, (float)this.parentTextBox.Width, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The up side of this solution is its is quiet simple and doesn't need new inherited textbox.

**1-2- Creating Transparent TextBox**

---

This way you should first Make a transparent text box and then set the background of it to your gridlines that you want. Since this way is also a way of creating custom paint textbox, you can customize the painting of that textbox too and bend it to your will.

Here is link to 2 greate articles that cover Transparent TextBox and Transparent RichTextBox:

- [Alpha Blended (Transparent Capable) TextBox and RichTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13197/Alpha-Blended-Transparent-Capable-TextBox-and-Rich)
- [AlphaBlendTextBox - A transparent/translucent textbox for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4390/AlphaBlendTextBox-A-transparent-translucent-textbo)

**2- Using RTF tricks**

---

There is some rtf tricks than you ca use to show grid lines in RichTextBox. One of best tricks is using tables in RTF. In below code We used 3 rows that contains a cell of width 2000 twips:

```
this.richTextBox1.SelectAll();
this.richTextBox1.SelectedRtf =
@"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0
{\trowd
\cellx2000
\intbl Street\cell
\row}
{\trowd
\cellx2000
\intbl City\cell
\row}
{\trowd
\cellx2000
\intbl Country\cell
\row}
}";
```

**Important:** When pasting above code in code editor, be careful to put no indents before richtext characters. If Visual studio inserted indent before them, you remove all indents.

Comment: Thanks to Andrei Alecu for his greate article about textbox custom paint in 2007, the codedblog.com is down now.

Comment: Very interesting. So there are good solutions both for `TextBox` and for `RichTextBox`. Thanks

Comment: @Reza - Thanks Reza this code is working, however, it looks like the line height is incorrect.  Every new line is drawn a tiny bit too soon.  The second method's line height is correct.  Is there a way to draw lines with rtf beforehand instead of using a table with rows and columns?

Comment: @langjacques You are welcome :) 
- About using rtf, Table approach is one of the best tricks while there are also some other tricks that those I know, are not as good as table or can't be shown in RichTextBox and only work in wordpad. 
 - I recommend using first approach. The screenshot has taken from execution on my system and it seems normal, but if you experience some problem during rendering of textbox you can try to increase height.

Comment: @Reza - Cool, I'm using the first method you provided and just subtracting 0.8F from the line height.  I'll do some more testing but for now it looks good!

Answer (score 0):

Start with this code:

```
class GridLineTextBox : TextBox
{
    public GridLineTextBox()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        var y = 0f;
        var lineHeight = e.Graphics.MeasureString("W", Font).Height;
        while (y < e.ClipRectangle.Height)
        {
            y += lineHeight;
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(System.Drawing.Pens.Aqua, new PointF(0, y), new PointF(e.ClipRectangle.Width, y));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code draws the lines but when I enter some text on the first line and do a carriage return the lines move down - almost like the text stays on the first line

Comment: actually, the lines don't move down, actually the line that you draw will be cleared when the GDI+ draws the text over it.

Comment: Mmm, so the lines will dissapear whenever you enter text, I would like for the lines to stay there

Comment: Yep, right now I can't find a better way to do this. There is the chance to overlay a `Panel` with the lines over your `Textbox` which is semi-transparent, and when clicking on it, directs the focus to the `Textbox`. But I find such solutions more troubling than necessary.

Comment: I agree - it seems like too much effort for such a small thing, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an RTF template file:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\trowd \trgaph180
\cellx3440\pard\intbl [0]\cell
\row
\trowd \trgaph180
\cellx3440\pard\intbl [1]\cell
\row
\trowd \trgaph180
\cellx3440\pard\intbl [2]\cell
\row
\para}
```

---

```
Dim fileContents As String
fileContents = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\temp\template.rtf")
Dim sRTF As String = fileContents.Replace("[0]", "line 1").Replace("[1]", "line 2").Replace("[2]", "line 3")
RichTextBox1.Rtf = sRTF
```